# Mock function is not called in click event while testing with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, sinon

I am trying to test a redux connected react component, namely Cart, and I cannot get the below test to work. I want to see if an action is called inside a click handler for a button (imported from the material-ui package).

The action is mapped to props via mapDispatchToProps.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(SelectItemGalleryActions, dispatch);
```

I am also using

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
```

to pass the mock store to my component in test.

The handler is called but the spy is not recording that it has been called. I have tried most solutions I have found here or on github (shallow, simulate, dives, using jest.fn() instead of spy() ...); do you have any ideas? I am assuming that a different reference to the mock function I am trying to test is called.

**First I am passing a mock store and an action**

```
const props = {
  store: mockStore({ selectItemGallery: { cartItems: [{ name: 'one' }] } }),
  removeAllItemsFromCartAction: spy()
};
const wrapper = mount(<Cart {...props} />);
```

**After that I search for my button and simulate clicks on it**

```
const button = wrapper.find(Button).at(0);
button.prop('onClick')('test1');
button.prop('onClick')('test2');
```

The clicks work when I run the test. I get console.log() outputs from inside the handler.

**Expectations**

```
expect(props.removeAllItemsFromCartAction.called).toBe(true);
```

However it is not called.

**Here is the actual handler**

```
 <Button
    color="primary"
    onClick={x => {
      console.log(`onClick called on component with info ${x}`);
      removeAllItemsFromCartAction();
      console.log('removeAllItemsFromCartAction call is above me');
    }}>    
        {t('Clear All')}
 </Button>
```

**The console displays**

[image: console output for test]

Any hints or ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Versions:

```
"enzyme": "^3.8.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"sinon": "^7.2.2",
"react": "^16.8.2"
```

Comment: Try button.simulate("click")

Comment: Thanks, already tried it and unfortunately still the same result.

Comment: Can you add how you setup your spy()? Usually its more involved than that. You need to define a variable you can refer back to. For example const myMock = jest.fn() and pass that variable into your props.

Comment: Already tried with jest.fn(); the spy() function is from import { spy } from 'sinon'; should work likewise but has same extra features for recording I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be **not** the correct way to test if an action mapped to props via `mapDispatchToProps` 
was called.

The dispatch from the mock store is actually called and we just need to verify if it sends the correct action (https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests).

The correct test would be:

```
  it('Should call the removeAllItemsFromCartAction', () => {
    const props = {
      store: mockStore({ selectItemGallery: { cartItems: [{ name: 'one' }] } })
    };
    const wrapper = mount(<Cart {...props} />);
    const button = wrapper.find(Button).at(0);
    button.prop('onClick')();
    console.log(props.store.getActions());
    expect(props.store.getActions()).toEqual([
      { type: 'REMOVE_ALL_ITEMS_FROM_CART' }
    ]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

These tests can be really finicky, but I suspect the issue is how you setup your spy since according to your console logs the function is getting hit. First, I don't think you actually need a spy and you could just use a mock function that is passed in as long as `removeAllItemsFromCartAction()` is actually on your component props.

```
const myMock = jest.fn();
const props = {
  store: mockStore({ selectItemGallery: { cartItems: [{ name: 'one' }] } }),
  removeAllItemsFromCartAction: myMock
};
const wrapper = mount(<Cart {...props} />);
const button = wrapper.find(Button).at(0);
button.simulate("click");
expect(myMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You probably have already tried this, but it is my only idea here.

Comment: Also, I'd see if this approach works with shallow instead of mount as well, just call .instance() and do the find on your instance.

Comment: Yes :( already tried it. But it should work like you said and if it's not maybe is something related to my env or buggy packages. Can you please tell me what versions of enzyme, jest are you using?